# VisioForge GAC & Packaging Assemblies for WPF App - BadImageFormatException

Tags: wpf, deployment, video-capture, gac

I have designed a screencapturing application which works perfectly OK in my computer. But I can't deploy its dependent libraries. We have purchase VisioForge and downloaded their SDK. I've almost tried everything to GAC their dll's coming from their package but still I'm getting an error telling me this

> Problem Signature 06:   5552079d   Problem Signature 07:    f2   Problem
>   Signature 08: 51   Problem Signature
>   09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException

after I've put all dependent dlls into the same folder I'm getting another error from the WPF app as this

> Problem Signature 09:   System.BadImageFormatException   OS
>   Version:  6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8

Anybody faced the same issue before? 
Is there any easy way to define all dependent assemblies of an executable file and make a deploy ? I've tried installer as well which didn't solve my problem.

This might be probably because of their x86 x64 libraries mixed. But tried those combinations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is probably because of x86 vs x64. See the [documentation from VisioForge](https://web.archive.org/web/20150617070653/http://support.visioforge.com:80/knowledgebase/articles/239922-deployment) on how to deploy. Use [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to get more information on the assembly loading process.

Comment: hello Lars. Have you used it before? We just need the screen capture libraries with the audio. But it crashes even if we distribute the base dist and mp4 dist. Which dists should I include in my setup ?

Comment: It's a nightmare to communicate with the person there. Can't just explain a very little thing.